# What will be the if statement to echo the strings of the array containing 'A'?

Tags: php

What will be the if statement to echo the strings of the array containing 'A'?

**Code:**

```
<?php
$students=array(
array('roll_no'=>1,'name'=>'Sagar','percentage'=>78,'grade'=>'A'),
array('roll_no'=>2,'name'=>'Rahul','percentage'=>50,'grade'=>'C'),
array('roll_no'=>3,'name'=>'Emir','percentage'=>60,'grade'=>'B'),
);
foreach($students as $array)
{
foreach($array as $value)
{
    if($value['grade']='A')
    {
echo $value;
    }
}
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11

Warning: Illegal string offset 'grade' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11
Aagar
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11

Warning: Illegal string offset 'grade' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11
A
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11

Warning: Illegal string offset 'grade' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11
Aahul
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11

Warning: Illegal string offset 'grade' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11
A
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11

Warning: Illegal string offset 'grade' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11
Amir
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11

Warning: Illegal string offset 'grade' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Assignment41C.php on line 11
A
```

Comment: 1) What is your expected output? 2) And what should `$value` be in the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need second `foreach`. Every `$array` value stores all `key => value` pairs. So you just need to check `grade` key's value:

```
foreach ($students as $array) { 
     // note a double `==` which is a comparison operator
     if ($array['grade'] == 'A') {    
         // print_r instead of `echo` cause `echo` won't output array properly
         print_r($array);             
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have used an extra loop here. Also, you might need to recheck this $value['grade']='A' part. Within if condition, a single = implies assignment operation. Use == or ===.

Try this to print the grade only:

```
   foreach ($students as $array) {
     if($array['grade']== 'A') {
         echo $array['grade'];   // To show the grade only
      }
   }
```

Try this to print all fields:

```
foreach($students as $array){
    if($array['grade']== 'A'){
        foreach($array as $k => $v) {
            echo "$k : $v";
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: i want to echo all the values  in the array and not the keys where A is also a value

Comment: Please take a look at my edited answer. The second one should solve your issue. :)